# How do I show $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f '(x)=0$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f '(x)^2 + f(x)^3 = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

$f(x)$ is a real valued function on the reals, and has a continuous derivative such that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)^2 + f(x)^3 = 0.$$

How do i show that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0?$$

Note I tried to take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ but it did not work

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: try f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x²} ,may this work

Comment: Not sure this matters, but is f smooth, i.e., infinitely-differentiable?

Comment: If f(x) is positive for some $x>0$, you are done, so only case left is when $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that : $\lim_{x\to\infty}f '(x)^2 + f(x)^3 = 0.$

1. Show $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0:$ Showing $\,\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x) \le 0$ is easy. If $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x) < 0,$ then $f(x) < -\epsilon$ for large $x$ for some $\epsilon > 0.$ Show this leads to a contradiction.
2. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ fails, then from 1., $\liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x) < 0.$ This shows there is $\epsilon > 0$ and sequences $x_1<y_1<x_2<y_2 < \cdots \to \infty $ such that $f(x_n)>-\epsilon /2,f(y_n) <-\epsilon $ for all $n$. Then for each $n$ $\min_{[x_n,x_{n+1}]} f = f(c_n)<-\epsilon $ for some $c_n\in (x_n,x_{n+1}).$ We then have $f'(c_n)=0$ and thus $f'(c_n)^2+f(c_n)^3$ does not approach $0,$ contradiction

Comment: Part 2 makes very little sense to me.

Comment: you can use LH rule may it also help :$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f '(x)^2+f(x)^3 = 0 $
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{{f(x)}^3}{{f'(x)}^2}=-1$
using LH rule...

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3f(x)^2.f'(x)}{2f'(x).f''(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3f(x)^2}{2f''(x)}=-1$
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{6f(x).f'(x)}{2f'''(x)}=-1$

Comment: Ok, now I can read it. I still don't get it. For example I don't see why there exist $x_n$ and $y_n$ with the properties you claim. Not that it satifies the other conditions, but note that if f(x) = -1 for all $x$ then $\liminf f<0$ but there are no such $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Comment: Regarding your comment, you should note that $a_n+b_n\to0$ does not imply $a_n/b_n\to-1$ (consider $a_n=1/n$, $b_n=1/n^2$.

Comment: I said in my comment it's may work ,not sure